# Adding jar files into eclipse in a LibGdx project

Tags: java, libgdx, libraries

I tried to add a jar file in the "core" project by doing:
right click in the project->properties->java build path -> libraries -> add external jars

And when I tried to see the class file it says "source not found" also it's giving me this error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

How can I add my jar files in a `libgdx` project?

Answer (score 0):

It is saying source not found because you need to attach the source files separately.

To do this, simply expand the `jar` file(s) in question (double-click on it, or click on the arrow in the library in the ***Java Build Path*** section.), and then click on `Source attachment`, and click edit. Then click browse on the window that will pop up, and find a file that is has a name likened to `src.zip`, or something similar, in the library's directory.

Essentially, this adds the compressed source package that may be required by that library, so it can access it.